# SQL returning extra data

Tags: python, sql, mysql

Hey there, was wondering if anyone could help a newbie on SQL and Python. I thought I had a pretty decent grasp of it, however something odd happened recently.

Here is the the following code snipped from a larger portion:

```
  try:
      self.db.query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = '{0}' AND pass = '{1}'".format(self.mail.strip(self.bchars),self.pw.strip(self.bchars)))
  except MySQLdb.Error, e:
      print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

  exists = self.db.store_result().fetch_row()
  print "EXISTS",exists
```

It use to print this:

```
EXISTS ((2, 'test@test.com', '1234', 1, 0, 2161, '192.168.1.47', 0),)
```

Now, it prints this:
It use to print this:

```
EXISTS ((2L, 'test@test.com', '1234', 1L, 0L, 2161, '192.168.1.47', 0L),)
```

I have no idea where these L's came from. I checked the SQL Database and even reloaded it to be sure. I have reverted all my code for the last day (where all was functioning), but still can't find a solution. I have also tried searching, but I am not even sure what this problem is even called so it's hard to search. Thanks for any help or information anyone can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, python's dbapi is supposed to always return integer-fields as long.

Anyway, 10L, 5L and so on is the way repr (which is used on every item of a tuple in your case) works for longs.

One more thing. I see, you are using MySQLdb. In that case, I strongly suggest, that you stop using the c-api wrapper, but instead use the "real" interface, that has all that automatic conversion/escaping and a bunch of other wonderful things (dict-cursors for one).

This will save you a lot of grief and WILL make your code more stable/secure. In short, just forget about _mysql. Trust me.

Your example can be rewritten as this (using the proper interface):

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=your_host, db=your_db,
                     user=your_user, passwd=your_password)

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = %s AND pass = %s """,
            (self.mail, self.pw))
result = cur.fetchall()
print "exists:", result
```

This does the same as you are doing (except the error handling), but without manual string-formatting, escaping and so on.

I know, this is going to be downvoted for irrelevance, probably, but if this answer helps even a *single* person to start using the *proper* database api, that would be really great.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize there was a different MySQL module to work with. I will definitely switch over to this way. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 2):

2L is the long version of 2: different object but the same value.

```
>>> print 2L == 2
True

>>> print 2L is 2
False
```

Are you running all the same (python, packages, db, OS...)?

Comment: Ohh I see. Yes, no additional packages, or changes in the python, the os, or the db itself since. What's odd is I have really outdated code that does virtually the same query and gets this as a result:
(('2', 'test@test.com', '1234', '1', '0', '2165', '192.168.1.47', '1'),)
I am sure there is something in my code... somewhere. However I never really specify longs or anything which just puzzles me. Thanks.

Comment: What is the db schema? What is the outdated code and what is the new code

Answer (score 1):

Is this because the data type in the SQL is 'long'?

As you can see in the tuple, they still are valid numbers, not strings, so this should not pose any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The L's indicate that the numbers are of the type Long. Your field types in the db are probably set to be of this type.